# Como hacer un distinct en un combobox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, combobox

```
 void addComboNombre()
        {
            int cliente = Convert.ToInt32(cboCliente.SelectedValue);
            var list = inv.Producto.Where(c => c.Cli_id == cliente).ToList(); 
            cboEstado.DataSource = list;
            cboCliente.DisplayMember = "nombre";
            cboCliente.ValueMember = "nombre";
            cboEstado.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

ese es mi codigo y quiero  hacer un distict para que solo refleje uno si esta repetido

Comment: No seria mejor decir que queres hacer un distinct en linq de tu lista inv.Producto?

Comment: Quiero que si aparece 5 veces el campo mueble lo muestre solamente una vez

Comment: Ok... Quieres hacer un distinct... Y por qué no lo haces?

Comment: Se puede hace pero eso te puede traer problemas, lo mejor es que valides a la hora de insertar ese dato si esta o no repetido y no dejar esa tarea al combo

Comment: @Japv no necesariamente es un problema de insercion.. si esta listando items de muchas facturas de un mismo cliente, capaz hay items repetidos ;)

Comment: y esto no sirve porque.... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0 (google, distint... la primera opcion...)

Comment: y donde tendria que poner el distict para que lo lea ?

Comment: en la lista que queres que tenga objetos distintos ;)

Comment: @gbianchi, el problema esta en que si hace distict, la información q se muestra en el combo(que para el es la misma, pero internamente no la es, ya que aunque es igual a sus ojos son registros diferentes) puede no ser la que desea exactamente seleccionar y en la tabla principal que es donde se guardaria la llave foranea del elemento seleccionado en el combo, puede ser perfectamente un registro diferente al q realmente selecciono

Comment: sip.. totalmente de acuerdo.. eso lo sabe solo OP... ;).. hay casos donde esta bien.. y hay casos donde no... @Japv

Comment: var list = inv.Producto.Where(c => c.Cli_id == cliente).ToList().Distinct();   en ese caso me tira error por que al cliente lo selecciono una vez pero el tema es que yo quiero que seleccione si ese cliente tiene 10 muebles y todos los registro aparecen como mueble yo quiero que en vez de que aparezcan 10 items con el mismo nombre solo me aparezca uno

Comment: si me podrian mejorar el codigo se los agradeceria